# Symlinking in monorepo - using lerna

Tags: reactjs, github, symlink, storybook, lerna

I am creating a monorepo component library with react, [lerna](https://lernajs.io/) and [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) to display my components. Each component gets its own package. This way I can import components to multiple projects with out needing the entire User Interface. The main issue that I am facing has to do with symlinking packages.

**Example:**

I have a Button component/package and a SlideoutMenu component both are unpublished. For display purposes in storybook/development. I would like to import the Button into the SlideoutMenu's story. So that I can use it to trigger the menu. Basically this is a dev dependency. It is not to be included in the build of the SlideoutMenu.

How do I link this type of dependency?

I have tried symlinking them using npm link which works locally but if I push the branch to github, at least currently the symlink is lost when a co-worker pulls the repository which obviously not ideal. Not really sure how to get symlinks to work with git/github

I have also tried to add the dependency like so inside SlideoutMenu's `package.json`

```
devDependencies: {
  "ui-button": "^0",
}
```

this works to import but if I update the `ui-button` components background color for instance. The `ui-button` dependency inside SlideoutMenu component will not be updated I tried running `lerna bootstrap` after making this update but it doesn't seem to update the installed package inside SlideoutMenu.

I would love some input on how to manage a monorepos dependencies and dev dependencies using symlinking and available to co-workers when pulling the repo from github.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how your packages are build? Do you use babel/webpack? They need to be build before the dependant projects sees an update.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the dependency was the first step.  Then you just call `lerna bootstrap` and it will link internally and install all external dependencies.   Anyone who pulls the repo needs to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a project that is very similar - a component library using React, Lerna, Yarn Workspaces, and Storybook. We had to tackle the same problem you're mentioning.

I've [published the code](https://github.com/Hy-Vee/lerna-yarn-workspaces-monorepo) to GitHub - try pulling this down and seeing if it works for your situation.

Hope this helps!